How do buffer overflows execute instructions on stack?
I have read a bit about buffer overflows.
One thing I don't understand is that normally stack space isn't executable. Then how can code placed in it, be run?

Exploits stopped executing code from the stack (or any non-code buffer, see W^X) long time ago. You way may want to check ROP, ret2glibc, JOP and similar.

The original 32-bit paging in x86 had no NX bit, you needed PAE or 64-bit mode for that (both of them use 64-bit page table entries with an NX bit). Segments on x86 can be marked as non-executable but segments mostly fell out of use, so for a while it was possible to execute data on the stack.

There is a binary protection call NX (Non executable stack). You can check the protections on any binary by running the command:
❯ checksec --file test

    Arch:       amd64-64-little
    RELRO:      Partial RELRO
    Stack:      No canary found
    NX:         NX enabled
    PIE:        No PIE (0x400000)
    Stripped:   No

Here the NX bit is enabled so pages can be non-executable.  Normal programs will use non-executable pages for their stack and anywhere else they copy user input to. This prevents the CPU from executing it as code: the CPU will raise a page-fault exception instead of doing code-fetch from such a page.  Only data loads and stores are allowed.  So for example overwriting a return address to jump to a buffer on the stack would result in a segfault.
The CPU treats data and instructions differently. Data is handled by the Data TLB and L1d cache, while instructions use the Instruction TLB and L1i cache.  In a page with read+write+execute permission, you can load and store as data and also execute the bytes as machine code; which of those things happens depends on what the program does.
To execute the injected code an attacker can exploit a vulnerability that allows them to redirect the program's execution flow. This means finding a bug that allows the attacker to change where the program thinks it should go next, such as changing a return address to point to their injected code.
In older systems NX bit was not present so all readable pages were executable. Hence shellcode injection was possible.  However these days these protections are present in almost all binaries. If you compile any binary, by default these protections will be on unless you specify otherwise using flags while compiling your code.
32-bit x86 without PAE page tables didn't have NX support in hardware.  So until Pentium Pro / II / III, and OSes that take advantage, 32-bit x86 OSes couldn't provide NX support.  x86-64 natively has NX.  Many OSes were conservative about backwards compatibility issues for 32-bit programs when making pages non-executable, in case of programs that depended on that, which is why binaries have to opt-in to NX support, and it can be disabled even for 64-bit binaries.

interpreted as code rather than data is far too strong a statement.  Unless the program is buggy, it won't actually execute the bytes as machine code.  Loads/stores to it are still data accesses that use the dTLB and L1d cache (not iTLB / L1i cache). A program using a data buffer in an RWX page is still using it as data.  Some kind of exploit is still necessary to get the program to jump to injected code.

On systems that support non-executable pages, reasons for making them executable anyway include GCC's C nested functions trampolines which used to use Linux's READ_IMPLIES_EXEC personality, not just makes the stack itself an executable mapping.  Unexpected exec permission from mmap wis assembly files included .  With hand-written asm, you have to manually include the right tag in every file to avoid the linker making your stack (or previously every readable page) executable.

Thank you for the insight sir, sorry for the incorrect explanation.

You can [edit] to improve your answer; I'd like to upvote it after it avoids misleading statements since your overall point is correct.  (Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

I have updated it from my understanding of your explanation sir, thank you so much for the knowledge you shared, I learnt something fun today.

I think your edit put way too much emphasis on the implementation details of CPUs.  I edited your answer to be closer to what I might have written, although still keeping a mention of split caches and TLBs since you wanted your answer to talk about that.  It's still your answer so if you want to re-edit any of that, feel free.  Or if you like what I wrote, then great :)
